# Remove application from launcher programatically in Android : Weird Exception

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am disabling a component(Activity) via PackageManager#setComponentEnabledSetting(),

which will have the effect of removing it from the Launcher.

But somehow I am getting below exception for some user(1% users) for this activity...

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException:

Maybe it takes some time for activity icon to be actually removed from launcher.

Please advice...

Complete Stack Trace..

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{packageName/packageName.ActivityName}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{packageName/packageName.ActivityName}
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{packageName/packageName.ActivityName}
   at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityName(SourceFile:284)
   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(SourceFile:153)
   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:123)
   at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:21)
   at packageName.ActivityName.onCreate(SourceFile:83)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: ComponentInfo{packageName/packageName.ActivityName}
   at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:263)
   at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityName(SourceFile:301)
   at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.getParentActivityName(SourceFile:281)
   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(SourceFile:153)
   at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:123)
   at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.onCreate(SourceFile:21)
   at packageName.ActivityName.onCreate(SourceFile:83)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Home screen launchers may elect to cache information that they get from `PackageManager` and fail to notice the change in the component's enabled status. I am not aware of anything that you can do about this, other than to avoid disabling a launcher activity in the first place.

Comment: Disabling launcher activity is not an option..
How else can this exception be handled?
Can there be any other reason for this exception?

Comment: Disabling launcher activity is not an option..
How else can this exception be handled?
Can there be any other reason for this exception?

Comment: "How else can this exception be handled?" -- if the exception is coming from the home screen launcher, you cannot handle it, as you did not write the home screen launcher. If you need more assistance, please edit your question to provide the complete stack trace, not just the error line.

Comment: did you mean uninstalling the app ....

Comment: @CommonsWare Added complete stack trace